# How to organize database table for many users?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm wondering what's the standard way to organize database table with tasks for your users.

Let's take a Wunderlist as an example - there are many users which stores they TO-DO tasks.

Should there be one `tasks` table with `user_id` column to determine who is the owner of the task ?

Or should there be many tables like `user1_tasks`, `user2_tasks`, etc... ?

Comment: You should have a fixed amount of table no matter the data inside, so your option to have "one `tasks` table with `user_id` column" is the best. You should also look into foreign key to make sure the `user_id` is valid

Comment: You shouldn't create tables like `user1_tasks`, `user2_tasks`, because this is not a scalable solution. How many tables would you create? let's say 5. What if you eventually want to have a list with six users?

Comment: And this is fine also from the security perspective ? to store data for many users in one table ?

Comment: Sure, filtering on a column within a single table is no different from selecting from a different table from a security standpoint

Comment: In relational data design anytime you find yourself adding numbers to the names of tables or columns, you are probably not doing the design right.

Comment: Yes, shared tables, schemas, etc. are fine.  Indeed it is the whole point of a shared database.  You achieve security through different means.

Answer (score 1):

If an user can have multiple tasks and a task can have multiple users, you need to create 3 tables : `users`, `tasks` and `users_tasks`.

`users_tasks` will be a table containing `user_id` and `task_id` and will create an element each time a task is assigned to an user.